# Reset vmstat statistics without rebooting

Tags: debian, monitoring, virtual-memory, statistics, vmstat

Running `vmstat` will give you the average virtual memory usage since last reboot.  The `si` and `so` values give the average virtual memory I/O.  For example:

```
root@mymachine# vmstat
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 1  0    304 300236 244940 967828    0    0     0     1    2    1  0  0 100  0  0
```

As Ijaz Khan answered, I can how many times I want `vmstat` to run, as well as the increments in between.  This is useful in some cases (+1), but I do not want to have to leave `vmstat` running.

I want to be able collect the data, then reset the counters so I can leave it for a while, then come back to get an average of from when I reset the counters to when I next check -- instead of since the last boot.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The memory information isn't averaged; `vmstat` shows the instantaneous memory information as provided in `/proc/meminfo`. So you can use the memory information from `vmstat` without worrying about changes since the last boot.

The values that are accumulated since boot concern the CPU usage, interrupts and context switches, and swap in/out and pages in/out; these are never reset. You can read the raw values from `/proc/stat` and `/proc/vmstat` if you want to be able to calculate your own deltas. For example, `si` is `pswpin` from `/proc/vmstat`, `bi` is `pgpgin` from `/proc/vmstat`.

Comment: `vmstat` is using old data as a part of the average, if the server has not rebooted in a long time.  I can't get a more recent I/O average just by calculating the difference... Unless I'm not understanding you.  Could you please clarify?

Comment: The memory information isn't averaged, so you can always calculate a difference on that.

Comment: Hang on -- `si`, `so`, `bi` and `bo` aren't averages???  I am mainly interested in the average `si` and `so`...

Comment: Only the memory information isn't averaged, the rest is. So you'd need to look at the raw values used by `vmstat`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following output:

```
$ vmstat 
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
0  0   3532 148760  50700 1397880    0    0     1     2    6    6  3  1 97  0
```

This data provides an average view of virtual memory and system usage since the last reboot. Often, the following form of the command is used:

```
vmstat [interval] [count]
```

In this example, the first line of data will provide the average since the last boot time ( which you can discard).

**Subsequent reports**, until **[count]** is reached ( will stop the vmstat), report data on the current state of the system every **[interval]** seconds.

Comment: See my initial post: "I know that I can specify how many times I want vmstat to run, as well as the increments in between. I do not want to have to leave vmstat running." -- I do know about that, but I didn't want to have to leave `vmstat` running for an hour...